# Creating a template to create, add, and format text boxes to a slide based on user input in PPT using VBA

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I have another questions that asks about the logic behind using several boolean radio buttons to ask survey questions, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953399/updated-how-do-you-automatically-create-new-shapes-on-a-separate-slide-based-on?noredirect=1#comment44307310_27953399). The largets issue I have had was getting the text boxes to populate a separate slide to display the systems that will affect the customer based on their radio button input.

This post is an attempt to find a way to reduce the code needed to create, place, and format the text boxes.  The below code is what I have so far, but it keeps telling me it expects an "=" when I run it.

```
Public Sub textBox(t As Integer, l As Integer, w As Integer, h As Integer, Sys As String)
Dim myTB As Shape

With ActivePresentation.Slides(7)
   Set myTB = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHotizontal, l, t, w, h)
   myTB.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Sys
   myTB.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255,255,255)
   myTB.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
End With

End Sub
```

I think I may have the logic wrong in declaring the variables. What I want to be able to do is simply place    textBox(200,300,200,25, "ERP Name") into my If Then or Case statement to format the boxes. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just as an FYI, you have to define each variable's type or it will default to Variant... `textBox(t As Integer, l As Integer, w As Integer, h As Integer, Sys As String)`

Comment: Thank you for the catch.  I tried updating the variables, but it still expects an "=" after the expression. I tried using it in an If Statement:    If Me.optFinYes.Value = True Then textBox(200,300,200,25, "ERP Name")

Comment: I figured out the issue. You have to call it without the brackets, ie. textBox 300,200,200,25, "ERP Name"  and it works

Comment: Or if you prefer to use parentheses, CALL textBox(parm, parm, ... , parm)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg  I totally forgot about the CALL code. Either way it works, but I do like the look of the parens better. Now if I could just figure out how to globally clear my presentation when someone re-launches it so my option buttons, check boxes, and form control text boxes are empty...

Comment: Simplest way I know to do that is to add a "landing page" sort of slide at the beginning.  It can contain whatever you like (introductory material for example) but it'd also have a "Start the show" button which fires a macro that clears your checkboxes/etc and then goes to the next slide.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I tried that using the cureent 'Begin' button I have, but the Select Case with the .clear push doesn't seem to clear any of the fields. I can't get it to clear the combo boxes, check boxes, or text boxes. I tried clearing the Text Range of the text boxes, and the Value of the others, but to no avail. I also can't find the object reference for calling a global check or option button. Also, could you post your CALL comment above as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use

```
CALL textBox(parm, parm, ... , parm)
```

or leave out the parentheses.

For clearing everything out, here's a starting point:

```
Sub ClearTheField()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
            If Left$(oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Name, Len("TextBox")) = "TextBox" Then
                oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Text = ""
            End If
            If Left$(oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Name, Len("CheckBox")) = "CheckBox" Then
                oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Value = False
            End If
            If Left$(oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Name, Len("CommandButton")) = "CommandButton" Then
                oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "I changed too"
            End If

        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That was EXACTY what I was looking for.  Those If...Thens really did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.  One useful thing to remember:  if you use VB or VBA forms, most of the properties of the form controls are available to the equivalent form control on PPT slides; the trick, as above, is to start with the shape's OLEFormat.Object then add the control property you're interested in.